# Identify the video frame size

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a generic way to get the height and width of a video and other metadata (like the timestamp when the video was taken, etc.) using .NET? I would like to get the size information of common video formats such as `.avi`, `.mpg`, `.mpeg`, `.mov`, `.asf` etc.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What video, in what context?

Comment: You should post your update as another question, as it's somewhat different from your original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but using DirectX you can use the [Video class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms902629.aspx) in the [AudioVideoPlayback namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb318762%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get the default size of the video. After creating the Video object, you can get the DefaultSize property, from which the height and width can be obtained.

A simple example:

```
    Video video = new Video(videoPath, false);
    Size size = video.DefaultSize;

    Console.WriteLine("Width: " + size.Width);
    Console.WriteLine("Height: " + size.Height);
```

Comment: thanks, will try it out
does it work for HD video too ? .m2ts/.mts etc ?

Comment: I found this useful as well. It may be worth noting that you will need to download the DirectX SDK or DirectX runtime. After doing that, I had to reference the Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.dll file under c:\windows\assembly\GAC.

Comment: To reference it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015217/cant-find-references-microsoft-directx-audiovideoplayback-and-microsoft-directx