# can't find references Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback and Microsoft.DirectX

Tags: c#, directx, xna

I've installed .net 4.0 as well as XNA 4.0 . A while ago I used `Microsoft.DirectX` to play some music and now when I try to redo the work, I can't find the reference. Did the new changes on the platform modify or moved something in the references?

Comment: Why don't you use XNA for the sound? The managed directX libraries aren't supported anymore as far as I know.

Comment: You should be using the XNA libraries now.  Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Audio, etc.

Comment: what is the advantage of using xna libraries over directx ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010:

right click on project

Menu select "Add reference..."

select tab "Browse"

select directory "C:\windows\assembly\ GAC\Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback

The DLL to reference is in that folder.

You will need to download and install the DirectX Software Development Kit first, if you haven't done so already.