How do I find out the resolution of the video?
I use Windows Media Player (WMPLib) to display the video.
To run a video on the form, I use this code:
Form form = new Form();
var wmp = new AxWindowsMediaPlayer();
form.Size = new Size(100, 100);
form.Controls.Add(wmp);
form.Show();
wmp.uiMode = "None";
wmp.Size = form.Size;
wmp.URL = "Video.mp4";

How can I dynamically find out the video resolution in the code to make the form of the same resolution so that there are no black bars on the form?
The fullScreen property does not help because it does not remove the black bars. I need to recognize the resolutions of not only mp4 video format, but other formats as well.

Accord.Video.FFMPEG (.NET Framework - see VideoFileReader's Width and Height. Example here)

(Accord.Video.FFMPEG) It seems that this option is not suitable, since it is only available on .NET Framework 3.5 and higher. And I am using .NET 8.0 (not Framework). Maybe this is not true, since I do not understand this very well

You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448853/identify-the-video-frame-size
